# Why can't I put 'Val' in function definition arguments. Error ':' expected but '}' found pops up

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-submit

I was trying to submit this code using spark submit. I found the following errors. I also would like to know how to do a function call in Scala and how do we start the function definition. I am calling `file_reading` function and I got the below error.

Here is my my function definition

```
def file_reading(file: String,val start:Int,val end:Int): Unit = {
```

Here are the Error I got:

```
/home/ram/sbt_project/src/main/scala/Scala_sample.scala:19:33: identifier expected but 'val' found.
[error]   def file_reading(file: String,val start:Int,val end:Int): Unit = {
[error]                                 ^
[error] /home/ram/sbt_project/src/main/scala/Scala_sample.scala:28:1: ':' expected but '}' found.
[error] }
[error] ^
[error] two errors found
```

Comment: The argument list of a def cannot contain the val keyword. This should read `def file_reading(file: String, start:Int, end:Int): Unit`

Comment: Just remove the val from start and end and add val to hdfs_connect2 and location

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please remove val in the method.

```
 def file_reading(file: String,start:Int,end:Int): Unit = {
```

Please correct for loop, next you will be getting error here.

paths ??

```
for(each <- file)
```

Comment: Why shouldnt I give 'val'?

Comment: you should not give sir, there are ways to follow. you can see the error,  error: identifier expected but 'val' found.  you can give it in case class like case class(var a:Int,val b:Int)